# How to use a lower resolution image for mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a responsive site using media queries to change the layout as the viewport size changes.

For mobile, I think it would be beneficial to use a lower resolution image to save on page loading times and bandwidth.

How would I disable the high quality image and replace it with the lower quality image using CSS?

Thank you.

Comment: Careful. Mobile screens nowadays can outdo some monitors. If JPG, you can safely keep quality of the image around 60% without any real difference (most of the time) which will knock off a great deal of KB size, and if you can, GZip & cache stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668535/responsive-design-different-images-for-different-screen-sizes

Comment: @DanWhite makes a good point, image optimization is definitely helpful. I wrote a little script you may find useful for that: https://github.com/ryanpcmcquen/image-ultimator

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the HTML5 `picture` element, you can specify inline media queries to size your images:

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="sm.png" media="(max-width: 400px)">
 <source srcset="mid.png" media="(max-width: 800px)">
 <source srcset="lg.png">
 <img src="lg.png" alt="MDN">
</picture>
```

The element will degrade gracefully to show the image tag in browsers that don't support it.

[Read more about the `picture` element on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

Also, [a JS polyfill](https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) in case the `img` tag fallback isn't enough!

Comment: Simplest, best answer! Even the ' <source srcset="lg.png">' is not required.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of this writing, the `picture` element has virtually no browser support.

So here are two alternatives:

- If the image is sourced in the CSS you can prevent it from loading with `display: none`.
- If the image is in the HTML `img` tag consider that the browser calls images from the `src` attribute. You can work around this by using the the [`data` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead. Apply `data` to all images and add `src` only when you want to load them.

**HTML**

```
  <img data-src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" height="100" width="100" alt="">
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $(this).find('img').each(function() {
         $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can develop your css spreadsheet file by adding display none for large images in mobile view, the new mobile browsers wont load large images if they contain **display:none** in css, allowing the page to load faster and also adding display non for small images in desktop view will do the same .

Answer (score -1):

It's simple - create another image with less resolution, and put it with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Media Queries can help you hide and show elements based on screen resolution and media type.

A great resource would be [this article about media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) on CSSTricks which covers different devices, platforms and res