# Changing Image depending on Mobile or Desktop HTML & CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, razor, model-view-controller

So im trying to change the image depending on if the user is on mobile or desktop version.

I have two different images, the one with an "m" in the end is a mini-version which is for desktop, and the other is for mobile. I cant get it to work though.

Here's some code:

HTML (Using Razor, so C# code works):

```
<img id="ifMobile1" src="images/arts/IMG_1447m.png" alt="">
```

CSS:

```
#ifMobile1 {
    background-image: url(/images/arts/IMG_1447m.png)
}

@media all and (max-width: 499px) {
    #ifMobile1 {
        background-image: url(/images/arts/IMG_1447.png)
    }
}
```

Help me please.

Comment: Have you tested on a mobile device? If so - what's the scale resolution of the device? I know my S5 is 3x

Comment: Yes I have tested it on a mobile device, the rest of my CSS code works so it's fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another trick would be to have two img tags, and hide one depending on the device.

HTML

```
<img id="img1" src="images/arts/IMG_1447.png" alt="">
<img id="img2" src="images/arts/IMG_1447m.png" alt="">
```

CSS

```
#img1 {display:block;}
#img2 {display:none}

@media all and (max-width: 499px) {
    #img1 {display: none;}
    #img2 {display: block;}
}
```

Comment: Display none does not prevent the browser from loading the image still. So this is actually worse as both images are loading on every device.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to live in the future, the `<picture>` element is the way to go. It still has really bad browser support (only blink based browsers, and firefox beta as of now). The good news is that it falls back to a dumb `<img>` tag, so no harm done except a little slower loading if it's not supported.

#### Alright, so how does it work?

*Most of this example is taken from [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/) with some modifications*

A picture element looks like this:

```
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 650px)"
    srcset="images/kitten-stretching.png">
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 465px)"
    srcset="images/kitten-sitting.png">
  <img 
    src="images/kitten-curled.png" 
    alt="a cute kitten">
</picture>
```

Try the example for yourself at http://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/, simply resize the width of the browser to see the kitten change.

The cool thing about the picture element is that it allows you to specify media queries to each of the `<source>` elements. The last `<img>` is shown if no `source` is matched, or if the picture element is unsupported.

Comment: Ahh the future... looks awesome.

Comment: Yes, the picture element has less support than srcset, but I don't see it as srcset version 2. They "kind of" do the same thing, but in different ways. srcset is better if it's the same image with different resolutions - the browser could then decide for itself what image to load depending on resolution, pixel density, and probably network speed in the future.

The picture element on the other hand you decide the images. This can be good or bad. If you want a different image on smaller devices it's the way to go.

Comment: @tony.gustafsson Oh thanks for the info! I thought the picture element was the thing that would stay. Do happen to know if one of them is on the way out?

Comment: @Ineentho No I think they are both here to stay :) There are parts of these standards that is not yet implemented in any of the browsers, but it will be awesome when we can use it better.

Answer (score 4):

Updated: Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/p96denv4/2/

Here's what you would do.

HTML

```
<div id="ifMobile1"></div>
```

CSS

```
#ifMobile1 {
    background-image: url(/images/arts/IMG_1447m.png)
    width: set your width  ;
    height: set your height  ;
}

@media all and (max-width: 499px) {
    #ifMobile1 {
        background-image: url(/images/arts/IMG_1447.png)
        width: set your width  ;
        height: set your height  ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try display: block and also make sure it is pointing to the right path of your image. Is your stylesheet in your main root?

Comment: Please see my JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/p96denv4/2/   Your background image should be showing. I don't think you can really use img tag to change the image source for mobile at this day and age. Due to browser support.

Answer (score 0):

```
img#id {
    content:url(http://example.com/image.png);
}
```

this may be of use to you, define each of your images in the respective media queries.

Comment: This is not useable on all browsers. IE, Firefox will fail as content:url() isn't supported

Comment: Tested in firefox version 36.0.1 and nothing shows? http://jsfiddle.net/3BRN7/406/

Answer (score -3):

you can't change an image source like that. You'll need to use a div with the original as a background image for this to work.

```
<div id="ifMobile1" style="background-image: url(images/arts/IMG_1447m.png);"></div>
```

Comment: And what about the CSS?

Comment: lol @Jackhardcastle really?? you think you can change an image source with css? you've down voted my answer and you have no idea what you're talking about?

Comment: That did not work, it has to be an img element, the div didn't show anything at all.

Comment: Use your original css with the height and width of the image applied.

Comment: Yes, I do believe that @Aaron

Comment: do you have a working example of this magic you speak of @Jackhardcastle

Comment: @Jackhardcastle I didn't think so... BECAUSE IT'S NOT POSSIBLE!

Comment: @Aaron I was on the phone with my bank. Hold on.

Comment: @Aaron

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-background-images/

Comment: wow @Jackhardcastle, one of the options here hides and shows 2 different images? nowhere on the example page you've provided does it change the source of an image?? Like I said originally, you have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle The majority of that article is talking about swapping a background image like my suggestion above (That you down voted!)

Comment: @Aaron I never downvoted it. 

Ofcourse you can replicate background-image as a CSS selector just as you can with background-color, background, ... 

I've no idea what I'm talking about, but I won't go into my profession, because this isn't the place. :^)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506069/media-queries-and-background-images

@Aaron

Comment: @Jackhardcastle you're point is still totally invalid, you can not swap the source of an image tag.

Comment: At my time of commenting @Aaron, that edit wasn't made to his example.

Comment: And yes you can, not with barebone CSS - but you can.

Comment: img {
content:url(http://example.com/image.png);
}

For example, add this into your media queries.

Comment: great if you're only looking at the site in chrome?

Comment: @Aaron - tested fire IE11 and FF and works for both.