# Changing image via media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to change a image when the display is smaller than  `400px` (for this purpose i cant use the image as background). I thought displaying 1 with `display:block` and to hide the other with `display: none`.

My question is if i do it this way, will the browser load both images and hide one of them or will it only load one of them? (`display:block`).
If the browser load both images i need to find a way to change the src of the image

Comment: Yes, browser will load both of the images.. Only after that, one of the image is hidden.

Comment: You can use the `<picture>` element along with the [picture fill polyfill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) to support unsupported browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid loading the image twice (not using normal css mediaqueries) you could use [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)  (JS);

```
var breakpoint = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 400px)" )

if (breakpoint.matches) {
    // window width is at least 400px
   // you load one img
}
else {
    // window width is less than 400px
    // you load other img
}
```

Comment: Huh, didn't know about matchMedia. Only [IE10+ support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia), but otherwise this looks like a good suggestion!

Comment: a name you can trust (p.irish) made a [polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) for that, but there are some issues so please test carefully

Answer (score 0):

ok .. you could check this stackoverflow post, [Media queries and background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506069/media-queries-and-background-images)  you must use min-width and mix-width into css and there is a webpage with more information for mediaquery´s assets http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use responsive images for that - new `<picture>` tag or `srcset` attribute for classic `<img>`. It is nicely explained here:

http://responsiveimages.org/

It is still quite new technique and it'ss not supported by all browsers yet ([srcset](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset), [picture](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture)), however there are polyfills (i.e. [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/)) that simulate it by JavaScript.